# Why have both variable and function concepts in C++ Concepts TS?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts, c++-ts

I've been looking at the C++1z [N4377](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4377.pdf) Concepts TS draft that is being implemented in GCC 6, and I don't understand the purpose of having two different kinds of concepts: variable concepts and function concepts.

The relevant part of the draft for function concepts is [dcl.spec.concept (5.4)]

- The declaration shall have a function-body equivalent to `{ return E; }` where `E` is a *constraint-expression* (14.10.1.3).

and for variable concepts, in the next paragraph [(6.3)] :

- The initializer shall be a *constraint-expression*.

Is there anything one of them can do, that the other cannot? If not, is there a rationale for including both?

<sub>Note: the latest draft, [P0121R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0121r0.pdf) doesn't change anything in this regard</sub>

Comment: Note: Concepts will not be in C++17, it was announced earlier this week.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I hadn't caught that. Tom Honermann's [Why Concepts didn’t make C++17](http://honermann.net/blog/?p=3) is informative, if anyone else wonders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function concepts can be overloaded on differing template parameter arity. Variable concepts provide nothing that function concepts don't, except for the ability to not put `()` in some contexts.

Eliminating variable concepts from the TS would not reduce the expressivity of concepts.

Comment: Within minutes, I found out this very answer in Tom Honermann's [Why Concepts didn’t make C++17](http://honermann.net/blog/?p=3) :)

Comment: Somewhat related: in D, one can elide parenthesis if the compiler can infer that a function call is being made. This makes long pipelines terser: `container.transform(v).reverse.print;` instead of `reverse()` and `print()`. If this were possible in C++, then variable templates would offer even less for concepts.